# PHP autoload can't find the class in php project

Tags: php, class, autoload, psr-4

[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoTkj.png)
I'm getting

```
 127.0.0.1:52368 [500]: GET /controllers/login - Uncaught Error: Class "App\Core\Database" not found in /path/to/my/Php/project/src/controllers/index.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in  /path/to/my/Php/project/src/controllers/index.php on line 9
```

and the class firing an error

```
<?php

namespace App\controllers;

use App\Core\Database;

//$conn = Database::getConnection();
try {
    $conn = new Database(__DIR__ . './../config.php');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
$query = "SELECT id, username, image, aboutme
            FROM users
                 LEFT JOIN persons on users.id = persons.user_id
            LIMIT 24";
$tbh = $conn->prepare($query);
$tbh->execute();
$persons = $tbh->fetchAll();
require_once basename("/") . 'views/index.view.php';
```

also my autoload_classmap.php

```
return array(
    'App\\Core\\Database' => $baseDir . '/src/Core/Database.php',
    'App\\Core\\DotEnv' => $baseDir . '/src/Core/DotEnv.php',
    'App\\Core\\Router' => $baseDir . '/src/Core/Router.php',
    'App\\Entity\\Person' => $baseDir . '/src/Entity/Person.php',
    'App\\Entity\\User' => $baseDir . '/src/Entity/User.php',
```

And I'm launching server from **src** directory :
php -S localhost:8000
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit ...
I'm calling index.php from url : localhost:8000 and even with this code in index.php

```
    <?php
    namespace App;
    
    //use App\core\Database;
    use App\Core\Router;
    
    require 'functions.php';
    
    //$config = require_once ('config.php');
    //$db = new Database($config);
    
    //require 'Entity/User.php';
    
    $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
    
    $router = new Router();
    $router->getRoute($uri);
    
    
    //require 'router.php';
```

```
I'm getting 
127.0.0.1:53738 [500]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "App\Core\Router" not found in
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How do you call that `index.php`? I don't see where you include the autoloader

Comment: What about the namespace of App\Core\Database class? did check it?

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Core;

use PDO;

class Database
{
    private static $connection;

    public final function __construct($config)
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:" . http_build_query($config,"",";");
        try {

Comment: Where do you include the autoloader in the `index.php`?

Answer (score -1):

You must create a class and add data inside it .

prepare($query);
        $tbh->execute();
        $persons = $tbh->fetchAll();
        require_once basename("/") . 'views/index.view.php';


}

Comment: "You must create a class" - what does that mean? Please add some explanation and formatting to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @Nico Haase Thank you . Your response gave me the hint